# how do I use while loop to display values of table in snowflake stored procedure using java

Tags: java, loops, stored-procedures, while-loop, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

create procedure proc(table String)
return String
language java

I have no idea how to use while loop in snowflake with java

Answer (score 1):

Java Stored Procedures in Snowflake work with a built in DataFrame API therefore they are different than working for example with JavaScript Stored procedure where you could loop over a resultset like this:

```
// Loop through the results, processing one row at a time...
while (rs.next())  {
   // Do something with the retrieved values...
}
```

You could though try something like this:

```
DataFrame df = getSession().sql("select * from values(1), (2) as t(a)");
Iterator<Row> it = df.toLocalIterator();
if (it.hasNext()) {
   if (it.next().getInt(0) == 1) {
      //do something here
   }
}
```

Also have a look at the DataFrame API from Snowflake [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/java/index.html).